# how to split JSON response data using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I am trying to get `Keys (A,B,...)` with related particular `record key` array values (city) from below `JSON` and try to store into `NSMutableArray`.

My JSON

```
response {
    A =     {

    "name" = janu;
    };
   B =     {
        "name" =   nandi;
        "record" =         (
                        {
                "city" = NY;
           },
          {
                "city" = CA;
           },

        );
    };
}
```

For Example:

1. I am checking `JSON response all keys` data without giving specific
   keynames (like: A, B, C,..)
2. Get record array of city values with `key (A,B,C,..)` and store into
   `NSMutableArray`
3. If anything new data came within `record` array, I want to show
   `notification` like below

---

### B :  NY

`FYI :` I need to store key with record array values Into `NSMutableArray` because I will compare `two array values` and show to the `notification` (by `remove object` to get new data), If anything newly arrived.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is not in the correct format. I changed it a bit ,and it looks like this:

```
      {
    "response": {
        "A": {
            "name": "janu"
        },
        "B": {
            "name": "nandi",
            "record": [
                {
                    "city": "NY"
                },
                {
                    "city": "CA"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the JSON keys as simple as this :

I assume JSON holds the JSON response ,and with

```
 JSON[@"response"][@"A"] you get the "name":"janu"
```

and with `JSON[@"response"][@"A"][@"name"]` you get the value "Janu"

and you can add this to your array,like this:

```
[yourArray addObject:JSON[@"response"][@"A"][@"name"]];
```